# Merge companies "Liferay" and "Liferay Inc." for developer stories

Tags: support, status-completed, developer-story

[Liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/342747/liferay?storyType=1) and [Liferay Inc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/367431/liferay-inc?storyType=1) both represent the company [Liferay Inc](http://liferay.com) on people's developer stories. The two should be merged into a single company, which should probably be called Liferay Inc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out! I have [merged](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/342747/liferay?storyType=1) the two lists.